# does `const auto` have any meaning?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants

I think the question is clear enough. Will the `auto` keyword auto-detect const-ness, or always return a non-const type, even if there are eg. two versions of a function (one that returns `const` and the other that doesn't).

Just for the record, I do use `const auto end = some_container.end()` before my for-loops, but I don't know if this is necessary or even different from normal `auto`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Maybe you are confusing `const_iterator` and `const iterator`. The first one iterates over const elements, the second one cannot iterate at all because you cannot use `operators` ++ and -- on it.

Note that you very seldom iterate from the `container.end()`. Usually you will use:

```
const auto end = container.end();
for (auto i = container.begin(); i != end; ++i) { ... }
```

Comment: `cbegin` and `cend` return a `const_iterator` by value. `const auto` still has it purpose and is not redundant.

Comment: So `const auto` is useful in this general case?

Comment: @dalle: I had removed my paragraph before you could comment, having realized that I had said just nonsensical things :)

Comment: @rubenvb: It can be useful if you want your variable to be `const`. Remember that it is usually possible to assign a const rvalue to a non-const lvalue.

Comment: @GMan: Wow, I didn't notice that terrible thing. Yes, that's what I meant and I hadn't tried to compile it!

Comment: Someone's been writing too much sql. :)

Comment: auto is modified by const as by &, it can be used in a foreach for example : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto

Comment: I think `/=` would have been a better mistake for the `!=`.

Answer (score 114):

```
const auto x = expr;
```

differs from

```
auto x = expr;
```

as

```
const X x = expr;
```

differs from

```
X x = expr;
```

So use `const auto` and `const auto&` a lot, just like you would if you didn't have `auto`.

Overload resolution is not affected by return type: `const` or no `const` on the lvalue `x` does not affect what functions are called in `expr`.

Comment: No. If you're not going to (or supposed to) modify the variable, it should be declared `const`.

Answer (score 7):

Consider you have two templates:

```
template<class U> void f1( U& u );       // 1
template<class U> void f2( const U& u ); // 2
```

`auto` will deduce type and the variable will have the same type as the parameter `u` (as in the `// 1` case), `const auto` will make variable the same type as the parameter `u` has in the `// 2` case. So `const auto` just force `const` qualifier.

Answer (score 3):

Compiler deduces the type for the auto qualifier. If a deduced type is `some_type`, `const auto` will be converted to `const some_type`. However, a good compiler will examine the whole scope of `auto` variable and find if the value of it changes anywhere. If not, compiler itself will deduce type like this: `auto` -> `const some_type`. I've tried this in Visual studio express 2012 and machine code produced is the same in both cases, I'm not sure that each and every compiler will do that.
But, it is a good practice to use `const auto` for three reasons:

- Preventing coding errors. You intended for this variable not to change but somehow somewhere in its scope, it is changed.
- Code readability is improved.
- You help the compiler if for some reason it doesn't deduce `const` for `auto`.

Comment: The compiler will not deduce const if it is possible... It will only add const if the expression it is deducing the type of is already const by itself. If a compiler would just add const for the sake of it being possible, program semantics might be broken, such as const vs non-const member functions being called depending on if the particular compiler can deduce the const or not. So I think your last point is wrong.

Comment: @rubenvb The C++ standards allow compilers to reorganize code in whichever way it suits them, depending on desired optimizations. It is perfectly legal for a compiler to deduce `const` for `auto` **if it is not changing program functionality in any way**. That also includes checks if there are const and non-const member functions available. Compiler will do it right.

Comment: _A good compiler will examine the whole scope of `auto` variable and find if the value of it changes anywhere. If not, compiler itself will deduce type like this: `auto` -> `const some_type`._  If you don't try to change the variable, how do you know if it's been deduced as `const` or not?  Anyway, I don't believe this.