# Is portability a concern with auto?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

`auto` is useful because you don't have to write out types. But what I want to know is if the type deduced for `auto` will affect the results of program on a system where the types might be different. Can a program I write using `auto` everywhere be portable or do I have to still worry manually about types?

Comment: I would be more worried about const and reference when using auto http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070521/does-const-auto-have-any-meaning

Comment: Yes you have to continue worrying to some extent.  For example, you could normally test and run on a platform that has a 32b int and everything works great.  Then your code gets ported to a platform that has a 16b int and suddenly your loop no longer does what you wanted because your loop counter is rolling over in an unexpected manner.  Such things are likely rare to bite you, but it is possible.

Comment: I would say that the type deduced for auto will be different on different systems, and that can _improve_ portability.  If you do use it correctly.

Answer (score 4):

If you need specific or minimum sizes for your types you probably need to utilize those types from `<stdint.h>` but otherwise there shouldn't be portability concerns with `auto`.

Comment: What about the quirks of integer promotion involving types bigger/smaller/same size as than `int` and `unsigned int`?

Comment: To add to this, you shouldn't be using auto because it lets you ignore types or save a few keystrokes, you should use auto because makes your code more correct and documents the intent of types in your code. Herb Sutter goes into a lot more detail on this [here.](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/)

Answer (score 2):

Is the result of `auto` portable? Well, let's take this simple example:

```
auto i = 123456;
```

Will this compile everywhere? Yes. Does it mean the same everywhere? No. On 16 bit systems, this will declare `i` as a `long`. Is that a problem? Not really. In fact, it happens to help portability by declaring a larger type where needed. But that's just luck:

```
auto i = 192 * 643;
```

overflows, although it's mathematically the same.

In a second example, you don't know what the actual type of `std::vector<int>::iterator` is, so `auto i = myVec.begin()` has an unknown type. And this type will differ between compilers. But again, those are details which do not matter. The important thing is that `i` can be used to iterate over (and change) `myVec`.