# Behavior of const auto pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, types, constants, auto

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5073644/1391081) claims that a const auto pointer behaves the same as a const 'regular' (i.e., non-auto) pointer, which is what I would expect.

However, the following code compiles and outputs `100`:

```
int n{ 99 };
const auto nPtr = &n;
++(*nPtr);
std::cout << n << '\n';
```

To dig a little deeper, I checked the types of all 4 kinds of pointers and this is the result I got:

*Code*

```
int n{ 99 };

int* intPtr = &n;
const int* intConstPtr = &n;

auto autoPtr = &n;
const auto autoConstPtr = &n;

std::cout << "intPtr: " << typeid(intPtr).name() << '\n';
std::cout << "intConstPtr: " << typeid(intConstPtr).name() << '\n';

std::cout << "autoPtr: " << typeid(autoPtr).name() << '\n';
std::cout << "autoConstPtr: " << typeid(autoConstPtr).name() << '\n';
```

*Output*

> intPtr: int * __ptr64
>
> intConstPtr: int const * __ptr64
>
> autoPtr: int * __ptr64
>
> autoConstPtr: int * __ptr64

So the compiler seems to be completely ignoring the const keyword with the auto pointer. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: `const auto nPtr` makes `nPtr` `const`. The resulting type is `int * const`, not `const int *`.

Comment: "So the compiler seems to be completely ignoring the const keyword with the auto pointer." no it does not, try to modify pointer itself (ie make it point somewhere else) and you will see.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you write `const auto`, you are saying: make the type of deduced variable, const. The type of the deduced variable is `int *`, that, is, pointer-to-int. So you are saying: a const variable, of type pointer-to-int. Or, more formally: `int * const`. The type of the pointee is still just `int`, non-const-qualified, so modifying is no problem. You just can't change what the pointer is pointing to. If you want to control the const-ness of the pointed to type, you can't just use `auto` because there's no awareness that it is specifically deducing to a pointer type. So you would have to write:

```
const auto * intConstPtr = &n;
```

The auto here is just deducing to the pointee (int), which is what gets qualified by the `const`. So this deduces to: pointer-to-const-int. You could also write:

```
const auto * const intConstPtr = &n;
```

For type const-pointer-to-const-int. Though, at that point, you should probably just use a reference. This is why const pointers (as opposed to pointers-to-const) aren't all that common in C++, at least in some codebases (there are certainly exceptions).

Answer (score 4):

Here, `const auto` is being converted to `int *const`, not `const int*`. The difference is that it’s a *constant pointer to a (variable) `int`*, not a *(variable) pointer to a constant `int`*. In this case, that means you can do `++(*nPtr);`, as you do, but you cannot change `nPtr` to point to a different `int`.

To see this, try adding the lines

```
int i{ 17 };
nPtr = &i
```

The four variants of `int` pointers with different `const` qualification, specified without `auto`, are:

- `int*`: A modifiable pointer to a modifiable `int`. You can change which `int` it points to, and you can use it to change the value of that `int`. This is what you get with just `auto nPtr = &n`.
- `int *const`: A fixed pointer to a modifiable `int`. It will always point to the same `int`, but you can use it to change the value of that `int`. This is what you get with `const auto nPtr = &n` or `auto const nPtr = &n`.
- `int const *` or `const int*`: A modifiable pointer to a constant `int`. You can change which `int` it points to, but you cannot use it to change the value of that `int`.
- `int const *const` or `const int *const`: A constant pointer to a constant `int`. You cannot change which `int` it points to, and you cannot use it to change the value of that `int`.